# Not able to pin secondary tiles on windows 10 desktop

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm trying to execute the notification sample from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications). I'm able to create secondary tiles in the windows 10 mobile but when I try executing the same program it gives me an System Exception:(The local device name is already in use.(HRESULT :0x80070055) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task).

This is happening soon after I execute the code

```
await tile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

Where tile is a `SecondaryTile` Please note I am able to send updates/Notifications to the Primary tile without any problem.

Edit: I've tried pinning secondary tiles from other apps like OneNote all of them crash. So I guess its a problem with the OS. 
I'm on 10586.36 build.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. This was most probably resolved by updates to Windows and/or VS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MSDN sample [Secondary tiles sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/secondary-tiles-sample-edf2a178).
(You might need to update the references to get the sample to compile/work)

It's scenario 6 you are looking for..